# Filter a date by current date in PowerQuery / PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm creating a report in PowerBI, and need to filter out some erroneous record from my source. Its a payment table, and some records are with a future date, eg in 2799. I'd like to make a Filter to remove records after today + 1 year. I already had this filter :

```
= Table.SelectRows(_cobranca, each [Vencimento] >= DATA_LIMITE)
```

`DATA_LIMITE` is a parameter, and the code above is already working. I tried to change it to :

```
= Table.SelectRows(_cobranca, each [Vencimento] >= DATA_LIMITE and [Vencimento] <= DateTime.LocalNow())
```

But I'm getting this error:

> DataFormat.Error: Syntax error in date in query expression '[_].[Vencimento] >= #2020-01-01 00:00:00# and [_].[Vencimento] <= #2020-10-21 10:58:07.4411693'.

It seems that DateTime.LocaNow function is not returning the date in the correct format.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you put parentheses around each inequality? I think it might be trying to `and` a couple of dates.

Comment: @AlexisOlson, I did what you suggest, but it didn't help. It showed the same error message. It seems it removes the parenthesis when it compiles the expression.

Comment: Nah, it's probably something different then. Are they all DateTime format or are the `[Vencimento]` column and `DATA_LIMITE` just Date type?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `DateTime.LocalNow()` with `Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())` as I assume your [Vencimento] column (due date?) is just a date data type not date time